# Using Devise, can I allow inactive users to still login but only to a landing page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

As I understand it, using Devise, inactive users are not allowed to login, instead will see an inactive user message on the login page. Can I change this behavior so that user is allowed to login, but only see a landing page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do this with a global `before_action` in your `ApplicationController`, redirecting logged in but inactive users to your landing page.

Comment: I am having an issue with adding a logout button on the landing page. Is it because `ApplicationController` redirects to landing page before `link_to "Log Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete` actually logs user out?